# Cooling a Roast cooked in a Crockpot

Tags: storage

What is the correct way to cool off a Roast/Pot/Carrots cooked in a Crockpot? Can I put it straight in the refrigerator after turning off or should I cool it off first.

Comment: I assume you want to cool this to store it longer term, or are you cooling to serve?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely cool off your roast first. Putting hot or warm food into your refrigerator a) shortens the life of your fridge because it has to work harder, and b) introduces heat into the fridge that can affect other items in the refrigerator. Shortening the usage date on milk is the most common. A third consideration has nothing to do with food but may impact your ability to purchase roasts in the future: your electricity usage. You're going to have to pay for every kilowatt-hour of electricity you waste on fridge-chilling food that is too hot.

Comment: It should be noted that A) the food needs to be cooled as quickly as possible and B) it doesn't need to be stone cold before it goes in the fridge. Luke warm shouldn't cause too much trouble for the fridge.

Comment: I rarely have much concern about dishes such as pot roast. They have a wide margin of tolerance for cooling. Dishes that involve pork, processed meats, high levels of fat, cream ingredients and other items prone to quick spoilage I treat differently. Pot roasts, beef or mutton oven roasts, or poultry I've raised myself are all items not prone to quick spoilage, so they can be adequately cooled before putting into the fridge.

Comment: I'd like to see some science on why beef or home-reared poultry spoil less quickly than pork or processed meats. This is the first I've heard of it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you're not a humid environment, leaving it uncovered outside the fridge, and stirring things every few minutes will help with evaporative cooling.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall -- I have no science. I have only experience. Maybe it's a question of hormones and steroids and impurities in commercial feeds, or maybe it has to do with the cleanliness of the environment in which the animals are raised. All I know is that different meats have different safe keep limits. For instance, a commercial chicken that produces milky juices doesn't last long, and I would never use it in a soup even if I could eat it. One that makes clear juices keeps safely in the fridge for 3 or 4 days. My own chicken lasts for 10 days in the fridge with no sign of spoiling.